# ActionBarSherlock при старте активити

Tags: actionbar, android

Использую ActionBarSherlock и при первом старте активити экшнбар появляется с иконкой приложения, хотя в коде я ее меняю, появляться заголовок, которого не должно быть, фон активити светлее, чем нужно! Через мгновение все встает на свои места! Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вы всё перечисленное делаете в коде? Используйте стили, темы и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Сейчас уже нету смысла использовать ActionBarSherlock. Так как компания Google добавила поддержку ActionBar в библиотеку support.v7. Можете смотреть уже туда.

[ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)